# How to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{2/3}a_{n}=\sqrt[3]{2}/\Gamma{(1/3})$

Tags: limits, power-series

Let $$\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{1/3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n,|x|<1$$

Show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{2/3}a_{n}=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\Gamma{\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)}}$$

Comment: The coefficients $a_n$ satisfy the linear 2nd order recurrence relation $(3n+6)a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}-3na_n=0$, with initial conditions $a_0=1$ and $a_1=\frac23$. Can anything be done with this observation?

Comment: @DavidH: How did you figure out that recurrence relation? Sorry if it is something obvious but I have never seen anything like it before.

Comment: @PranavArora Heh, I didn't figure it out at all. WolframAlpha told me that it's so, therefore it must be so. Is that obvious enough for you? =D

Comment: @DavidH: lol. :D But still, is there a way to find it without the help of W|A?

Comment: You have $\log f(x) = \frac{1}{3}\left(\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)\right)$, hence $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{2}{3(1-x^2)}$ implies $f'(x)(1-x^2) = \frac{2}{3}f(x)$, giving the recurrence relation $(n+1)a_{n+1}-(n-1)a_{n-1}=\frac{2}{3}a_n$.

Answer (score 7):

Using the binomial theorem and the Cauchy convolution we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}[z^h]\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^{1/3}&=&(-1)^h\sum_{l\leq h}\binom{-1/3}{l}\binom{1/3}{h-l}(-1)^l\\ &=& (-1)^h\binom{-1/3}{h}\cdot\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(-\frac{1}{3},-h;\frac{2}{3}-h,-1\right).\end{eqnarray*}\tag{1}$$
Since:
$$\lim_{h\to+ \infty}\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(-\frac{1}{3},-h;\frac{2}{3}-h,-1\right)=(1+1)^{1/3}=2^{1/3},\tag{2}$$
we just have to study the asymptotic behaviour of:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\binom{-1/3}{n}&=&\frac{\Gamma(2/3)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(2/3-n)}=\frac{\Gamma(2/3)\Gamma(1/3+n)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(2/3-n)\Gamma(1/3+n)}\\
&=&\frac{\Gamma(2/3)\sin(\pi n+\pi/3)}{\pi}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(n+1/3)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\\&=&\frac{(-1)^n\,\Gamma(2/3)\sqrt{3}}{2\pi}\cdot n^{-2/3}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\end{eqnarray*}\tag{3}$$
so the limit is:
$$\frac{2^{1/3}}{\Gamma(1/3)}\tag{4}$$
due to the Euler reflection formula.

Comment: How is the limit of the hypergeometric calculated?

Comment: The coefficients are products of two ratios of values of Gamma function, the second ones converging very fast (as $h\to +\infty$) towards one, giving that $\phantom{}_2 F_1$ "degenerates" into $(1+x)^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 4):

Write

$$
\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{1/3} = \frac{(1+x)^{1/3} - 2^{1/3}}{(1-x)^{1/3}} + \frac{2^{1/3}}{(1-x)^{1/3}} =: f(x)+g(x).
$$

The function $f$ is continuous on the disk $|z| \leq 1$, so by Darboux's method (Thm. VI.14 in [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)) we have

$$
[x^n] f(x) = o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$

The coefficients of the second series are given by

$$
[x^n] g(x) = 2^{1/3} (-1)^n \binom{-1/3}{n} = \frac{2^{1/3}}{\Gamma(1/3) n^{2/3}} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^{5/3}}\right)
$$

[as shown by Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/856896/5531).

Combining these yields

$$
\begin{align}
[x^n]\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{1/3} &= [x^n] f(x) + [x^n] g(x) \\
&= \frac{2^{1/3}}{\Gamma(1/3) n^{2/3}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right),
\end{align}
$$

so that

$$
n^{2/3} [x^n]\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{1/3} = \frac{2^{1/3}}{\Gamma(1/3)} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}\right).
$$

Comment: Could the downvoter please comment?  I believe the answer is correct though I am new to Darboux's method so I may not have applied it properly here.  If that's the case then I would like to know.